# Initialize integer variable on typedef in C

Tags: c, typedef

I have a definition for int with my preferred name like so

**Step 0** :

### define array type of 128 elements

```
typedef int ishida_opcua_array[128];
```

and later i have a function to initialize the type `ishida_opcua_array`

```
void ishida_opcua_array_init(ishida_opcua_array array)
{

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 128; i++)
            array[i] = -56565;

}
```

And finally; this is how i use the `ishida_opcua_array` type

**Step 1** :

### define an array of type ishida_opcua_array

```
 ishida_opcua_array source_array;
```

**Step 2** :

### Initialize source_array with ishida_opcua_array_init() function

```
 ishida_opcua_array_init(source_array);
 /*
  * Then i can do whatever i want with [source_array]
  */
```

How can i declare and initialize the array with the typedef, i want to be able to do

```
/*
 * Define the variable and you are ready to go
 * initialization has already been done while creating the variable
 */
ishida_opcua_array already_initialized_array;  //already initialzed, ready to use
```

Please note in the first step, i had to first define the variable like so

```
ishida_opcua_array source_array;
```

then initialize the variable using below function

```
ishida_opcua_array_init(source_array);
```

Comment: Typedef defines a type, you cannot use it to initialise objects of that type.

Comment: @n.m is there another way to do it ?

Comment: To all those who down comment, would you care to explain why you are down commenting ?

Comment: Calling `ishida_opcua_array_init` is a good way to do it. I'm not sure why you want to do it in any other way. What's wrong with calling a function?

Comment: not down voter - but I'd guess that it's because they're confused about what you're asking

Comment: didnt downvote, but there is literally no question, striclty speaking no mcve but only fragments and imho you should explain why you think a typedef has anything to do with initialization of a variable.

Comment: i am more interested in having a default initialization i.e. when ishida_opcua_array already_initialized_array is done, the variable should contain say 10 elements with each element having the value -56565 , i do not want the user of the type to call an initialization function, i want the initialization to happen in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
ishida_opcua_array already_initialized_array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Of course, this would only initialise the first three members specifically and the rest to 0; you could use macros to generate your initialiser:

```
#define INIT_0 -56565          // well, prefer a better name...
#define INIT_1 INIT_0, INIT_0
#define INIT_2 INIT_1, INIT_1
```

up to `INIT_7` and then have

```
ishida_opcua_array already_initialized_array = { INIT_7 };
```

Not going to judge if this really is better than your function...

Comment: Your approach is slightly similar to what i have so far, i am more interested in having a default initialization i.e. when ishida_opcua_array already_initialized_array is done, the variable should contain 10 elements with each element having the value -56565

Comment: In C, all that comes to my mind would be another macro: `#define ISHIDA_OPCUA_ARRAY(NAME) ishida_opcua_array NAME = { INIT_7 }`... C++ would offer constructors for such purposes...